# I'm looking for a gdb that can run on an Android device. My toolchain is arm-linux-androideabi

Tags: android, arm, gdb

I want to run gdb directly on my Android device using the command line, instead of using gdbserver to debug my binary executable file.
I tried to download the official gdb source code and the Android gdb source code, and compile them using my toolchain. However, my compilation has been failing.
The official gdb source code can be compiled successfully, but when debugging the files, it shows "not in executable format: File truncated". The Android gdb source code has been failing to compile. My head is about to explode.

Does anyone have a gdb binary executable file that can be directly run on the Android platform, could you please send it to me to try?
Or if anyone has a tutorial, could you please provide it to me.